# How to get multiple ResultSets by executing multiple SQL queries at the same time in Apache Ignite?

Tags: java, ignite

I am using Apache Ignite for the data caching, In that I have used SQL Grid to store data. While fetching ResultSets from the multiple SQL queries, I have to execute each query separately. So Is it possible to execute all SQL queries once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither JDBC nor Ignite native SQL APIs are asynchronous, so you will need to write your own helper for that (possibly by using multiple threads to query in parallel).

You could also use `preparedStatementsList.stream().map(PreparedStatement::executeQuery)` by leveraging Java 8 Streams.

Comment: Is Apache Ignite support SQL batch query?

Comment: @Rhishi Yes, it does.

Comment: Can you provide document or example for this?

Comment: https://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/ should be OK, also check out https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/set

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to tell what you mean, but I'll try...

You can execute multiple SQL queries in parallel, but you need to use separate JDBC connections (I can tell you're using JDBC because you're talking about `ResultSet`) - one connection per thread.

Comment: I want to execute multiple queries with one connection only. As SQL used Batch Queries